# Redshift: how to match longest regex string from a list of strings

Tags: regex, amazon-redshift

context:

I am currently working on parsing error messages, and the way I went about it, albeit a bit hacky, is to tag the longest string with a custom error type.
So I have a dictionary of substrings as such:

```
{'abcdefg' : 'Error A', '1234' : 'Error B', 'aaa' : 'Error C'}
```

For instance:
If i had an error string:
`'abcdefg1234'`, I want to match it to Error A because `abcdefg` is the longest tagged substring in the message.

`'abc1234aaa'` would return `'Error B'`.

I believe the idea would be to first append the longest substring, and then join on the tag dictionary table.

I know how to do 1 regex match, but I do not know how to loop through a list to find the longest matching one.

Answer (score 0):

SQL isn't a procedural language and doesn't have a concept of looping (generally).  I like to think of it as a parallel merging and filtering language.  So to perform what you want you need to do a few steps

1. Convert your json dict to a table
2. Join this table to the table with the error strings being evaluated table ON a LIKE condition that tests if the error test value is in the error string
3. Evaluate the length of each match and order these lengths to find the longest (window function row_number() would be my choice)

The resulting SQL will look something like:

```
SELECT error_message,
    TYPE
FROM   (   
           SELECT    error_message,
                  TYPE,
                  Row_number () over (PARTITION BY error_message ORDER BY length DESC) AS rn
           FROM      message_table
           left join       
                  (   
                      SELECT 'Error A'                          AS TYPE,
                          Json_extract_path_text(pattern_json, 'Error A')      AS pattern,
                          Len(Json_extract_path_text(pattern_json, 'Error A')) AS length
                      union ALL
                      SELECT 'Error B'                          AS TYPE,
                          json_extract_path_text(pattern_json, 'Error B')      AS pattern,
                          len(json_extract_path_text(pattern_json, 'Error B')) AS length
                      UNION ALL
                      SELECT 'Error C'                          AS TYPE,
                          json_extract_path_text(pattern_json, 'Error C')      AS pattern,
                          len(json_extract_path_text(pattern_json, 'Error C')) AS length )
           ON     pattern LIKE '%'+pattern+'%'
) 
WHERE rn = 1;
```

This code isn't tested and I've made a number of assumptions about what you are doing but hopefully this will give you a path to start from.